# Handle Azure web app timeout error to send ApplicationInsights traces

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, azure-application-insights

We have a webapi wep app deployed in Azure. We receive a POST request that takes longer that 230 seconds to finish. Azure is then killing the request and sending a 500 error response.

My problem is that all Application Insights telemetry and error traces for that POST request are lost when the request is killed. What can I do to get the traces sent to Application Insights? (Traces are correctly sent in normal execution of other request to that web app, even when the request return errors other that this timeout special case. We only lose the traces in case of this timeout error).

Our web app is using a `AppInsightsExceptionTracker` inside the `Handle()` and `HandlerAsync()` methods of a `System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler`. We register that exception handler in `WebApiConfig.Register` method of the web api `WebApiConfig` class, like this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```

We guess our problem is caused by the exception handler not being invoked in case of a timeout managed by Azure instead of a real error returned by our webapi. How can we handle that error and make sure the traces are written?